# Очистить ресурсы при завершении программы

Tags: lua

Как выполнить что-либо при завершении работы программы? Знаю про финализаторы, но ресурс явно не привязан к какой-либо части программы.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Данный функционал легко реализуется через модуль:

```
local finaltab = {}; -- таблица

return {
        create = function(nam, func)
                local tab = {} -- инициализировать таблицу-финализатор
                setmetatable(tab, {__gc = func}) -- назначить функцию-финализатор
                finaltab[nam] = tab -- добваить таблицу-финализатор в хранилище финализаторов
        end;
        delete = function(nam)
                setmetatable(finaltab[nam] or {}, {}) -- отключить финализатор
                finaltab[nam] = nil -- просто стереть
        end
}
```

Пример использования:

```
finalizers = require 'finalizers'
finalizers.create('Final', function() print 'Bye!'; end)
print('Hello!')
```