# Остановка сервера luasocket+copas при завершении программы

Tags: сервер, lua

Я использую `luasocket` и `copas` для работы сервера чата. Необходимо освободить порт (т.е. `server:close()`) при завершении программы. Как можно выполнить данную задачу, по возможности не используя C?

Попыткии использования [модуля](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/519058/%D0%9E%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%83%D1%80%D1%81%D1%8B-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D1%8B) не помогли, т.к. финализатор сервера вызывался до финализации клиентов (я их отключаю тоже финализаторами).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Очевидно, просто не вызываются финализаторы. Для корректного выхода используйте `return` в главной функции. Иными словами, сделайте проверку на условие выхода, добавьте с помощью `copas.addthread`. Важно, чтобы функция не блокировала цикл, а после проверки вызывала `copas.sleep()`. Вместо `copas.loop` тогда используйте

```
while not exitnow do
    copas.step()
end
```

UPD: или используйте `os.exit(exitcode, true)`.